# Rebuilding workspace after kinetic update?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there. After the latest update I'm encountering various breakages and processes dying on startup. For example a `Time is out of dual 32-bit range` error. Should my workspace and ROS nodes etc be built after a large update like this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303093/rebuilding-workspace-after-kinetic-update?/) by [NotABot](https://answers.ros.org/users/37446/notabot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-09-11

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-09-11**:
Probably. It would help to know if you're just upgrading packages within Kinetic, or upgrading from an older version of ROS (Indigo, Jade, etc) to Kinetic.

**Comment by [NotABot](https://answers.ros.org/users/37446/notabot/) on 2018-09-11**:
From an older version of Kinetic. Is it possible to roll back to previous versions of the packages? Or reinstall without that update?

**Comment by [lstelzner](https://answers.ros.org/users/30930/lstelzner/) on 2018-09-11**:
We've also been having issues with a kinetic build that seems to have been released approx 4 days ago. We build all our ros into docker containers, I have a docker from 5 days ago that launches our stack fine, the one from 4 days ago fails. Half of the nodes die on launch without any useful logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a release of package updates for Kinetic a few days ago: https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-kinetic-2018-09-06/5983 . It looks like that included releases of lots of packages.

It sounds like you're seeing either an ABI compatibility issue, or a bug introduced by one of the changes in one of the packages that was updated. In general ROS strives to maintain backward compatibility with these updates so that you don't need to recompile when you update packages, but sometimes the packages maintainers make mistakes, or it's just not possible.

If this is an ABI compatibility issue or a new bug, it should be reported upstream immediately so that the maintainers can decide how best to handle it. If you're not sure which package or stack to report this issue on, I suggest you update your question with the exact error message that you're seeing, or ask a new question that includes the exact error message.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-12**:
This was most likely an ABI breakage: we've had several workspaces 'break' after the latest sync. All of those fixed by updating *all* ROS pkgs (not just a few of the outstanding updates) and then rebuilding the workspace.

Rebuilding after a `apt` update is always recommended.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer the OP question: Yes. It looks like you need to recompile.

We were seeing a (related) issue with our docker builds, however we *were* compiling our code in the image.  Our problem looks like it is from the released ros:kinetic docker image not having the latest update in it (despite being updated 6 days ago).  So the packages we were installing were built against a newer (non-backward compatible) versions of base packages than were installed on the image (*and* those packages didn't call out needing the newer base packages).

**Needed action from OSRF**: Update the ros:kinetic docker image

I assume the docker image is built inside the build farm and triggered by the release, so I'm a little surprised that it is behind.  I think something needs to be updated on the build farm to prevent this from happening again.

---

Originally posted by [athackst](https://answers.ros.org/users/37465/athackst/) with karma: 31 on 2018-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2